# How to check if NFC available for iOS using ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, nfc, ios12, ndef

I wanted to know is it possible to check using ionic if iOS device has NFC functionality. I can use "PhoneGap NFC Plugin" but it only has `nfc.beginSession()` function which isn't what I need because it opens NFC reading window for iOS but I just want to check if available without opening any windows. I know that you can call in swift `NFCNDEFReaderSession.readingAvailable()` but is there a plugin which offers  what I need?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/nfc/ Go through this link . Its mentioned in this doc that supported platforms for NFC in ionic are Android,BlackBerry 10,Windows,Windows Phone 8

Comment: @DikshaBhargava I have done it multiple times, but it doesn't exactly answer my question.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/diagnostic/#NFCState This specifies your answer , to check if iOS device has NFC functionality it is mentioned it is not for iOS . Please check these functions in the doc >> isNFCPresent() , >> isNFCAvailable() in NFCState . These are possible in android.

Comment: @DikshaBhargava I know that it is only possible to check for Android, but I was asking is any other methods, plugins that could do it because is native could it is possible to do it in iOS. For example, I was thinking of checking for specific iPhone models which doesn't have NFC and show NFC read button for every other phone...

Comment: https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/blob/master/src/ios/NfcPlugin.m have you checked this out ? In - (void)pluginInitialize method ![NFCNDEFReaderSession readingAvailable is done in it .

Comment: @DikshaBhargava Oh, I see. But I don't think I will be able to extract the method as plugin function. It will be too complicated for my level of skill.

Comment: @MārtiņšCiekurs What exactly prevents you from using the `enabled()` method provided by the plugin? On iOS, this seems to do exactly what you want...

Comment: @MichaelRoland ok, confirmed, need to drink more water #facepalm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `enabled()` method of the phonegap-nfc plugin seems to do exactly what you want on iOS: it internally calls `NFCNDEFReaderSession.readingAvailable()`.